# Image slider pages printing issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to create image slider view to view 3 pictures as slider. But every time it is creating only one picture with 3 slides. So please where would be my issue?

Should it print an image in each page slide?

```
- (void)imageCreater{

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

CGRect svrect_ = CGRectZero;
svrect_.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height/3*2;
svrect_.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width/3*2;
CGPoint svcenter_ = CGPointZero;
svcenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
svcenter_.y = self.view.center.y+45;
CGSize svconsize = CGSizeZero;
svconsize.height = svrect_.size.height;
svconsize.width = svrect_.size.width * 3;

CGPoint pgconcenter_ = CGPointZero;
pgconcenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
pgconcenter_.y = svcenter_.y + (svrect_.size.height/2) + 20;

CGRect btnrect_ = CGRectZero;
btnrect_.size.width = 250;
btnrect_.size.height = 50;
CGPoint btncenter_ = CGPointZero;
btncenter_.x = self.view.center.x;
btncenter_.y = self.view.bounds.size.height-65;

_backgroundimageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_backgroundimageview];

_scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
_scrollview.center = svcenter_;
_scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_scrollview.contentSize = svconsize;
_scrollview.pagingEnabled = true;
_scrollview.bounces = false;
_scrollview.delegate = self;
_scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
_scrollview.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollview];

_pgcontrol = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_pgcontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1];
_pgcontrol.numberOfPages = 3;
_pgcontrol.currentPage = 0;
[_pgcontrol sizeToFit];
_pgcontrol.center = pgconcenter_;
[self.view addSubview:_pgcontrol];

UIImageView*iv_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31902.png"];

UIImageView*iv1_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv1_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv1_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv1_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31901.png"];

UIImageView*iv2_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv2_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv2_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv2_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"31900.png"];

[_scrollview addSubview:iv_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv1_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv2_];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

int page_ = (int)round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
if (page_== inter-1) {
    [_button setTitle:startText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
    [_button setTitle:nextText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
_pgcontrol.currentPage = page_;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the same frame to the three imageView
Change the frame as mentioned below, you will get three image in slideView

```
UIImageView*iv_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-1.jpg"];

svrect_.origin.x += iv_.frame.size.width;

UIImageView*iv1_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv1_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv1_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv1_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-2.jpg"];

svrect_.origin.x += iv1_.frame.size.width;

UIImageView*iv2_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:svrect_];
iv2_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv2_.clipsToBounds = true;
iv2_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-3.jpg"];

[_scrollview addSubview:iv_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv1_];
[_scrollview addSubview:iv2_];
```